# How do I change the login sound

Tags: 20.04, sound, startup

So I recently enabled the login sound, but I don't like it that much. Is there a way to change the login sound? I tried searching on the internet, but it gave me super outdated results from 2012. Is there a specific login.ogg file or something? Or how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are looking for is located at `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo/desktop-login.oga` if you are using the Yaru (default) theme.

Comment: You might want to add how to actually change the login sound when the file is found... I suggest.